# returning a string from a function

Tags: c++, string, c++11, return-value, move-semantics

I wanted to write a function that'll be cross platform (win32 & linux), and return a string representation of the datetime [hh:mm:ss dd-mm-yyyy].

Knowing that I just want to use the returned string as a temporary in a stream fashion as below:

```
std::cout << DateTime() << std::endl;
```

I considered writing a function with the following prototype

```
const char* DateTime();
```

If you return a character array, you must delete it once you're done.  But I just want a temporary, I don't want to have to worry about de-allocating the string.

So I've written a function that just returns an std::string:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string DateTime()
{
    using namespace std;

    stringstream ss;
    string sValue;
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

    ss << now->tm_hour << ":";
    ss << now->tm_min << ":";
    ss << now->tm_sec << " ";
    ss << now->tm_mday + 1 << " ";
    ss << now->tm_mon + 1 << " ";
    ss << now->tm_year + 1900;

    sValue = ss.str();

    return sValue;
}
```

I realize that I'm returning a copy of the stack variable in DateTime.  This is inefficient in that we create the string on the DateTime stack, populate it, then return a copy and destroy the copy on the stack.

Has the c++11 move-semantics revolution done anything to resolve this inefficiency - can I improve upon this?

Comment: 1) NRVO makes this a complete non-issue. 2) If NRVO _didn't_ kick in for whatever reason, then yes, the return value would be moved rather than copied.

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/484072

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: @lapin: named return value optimization. Instead of copying a value (perhaps multiple times) to get from the called function back to the caller, the compiler passes the function a hidden pointer to the location where it will end up being assigned, and the function uses that location for its local variable.

Comment: like other have said RVO is guaranteed if you are using C++11, however I wouldn't worry because the string stream will be the bottle neck here.

Comment: @111111 : RVO is never guaranteed in the standard (98, 03, or 11), merely permitted. It's up to the implementation to make guarantees regarding this particular optimization.

Comment: `tm_mday + 1` - you should remove this `-1`, `tm_mday` is 1-based.

Comment: I was surprised no one else noticed that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lapin, your code is fine C++11 code.  In C++98/03 your code will *probably* be efficient due to compiler optimizations, but those optimizations aren't guaranteed.  In C++11, those same optimizations will probably still make your return free, but just in case they don't, your string will be moved instead of copied.

So return by value guilt-free! :-)

Minor nit:

It is best practice to declare your values at the point of first use, instead of at the top of a block:

```
string sValue = ss.str();
return sValue;
```

Or perhaps even:

```
return ss.str();
```

But this is just a minor nit.  Your code is fine *and* efficient.

Comment: I started the (bad?) habit of declaring my variables before my code when I was writing far too many MSSQL stored procedures a few years ago.  I've heard your point before on declaring vars at the point of first use for efficiency, and I agree with it, but I still find myself declaring before the code :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is to make it a function object with a stream inserter, as in:

```
struct DateTime()
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DateTime)
    {
        time_t t = time(0);
        struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

        os << now->tm_hour << ":";
        os << now->tm_min << ":";
        os << now->tm_sec << " ";
        os << now->tm_mday + 1 << " ";
        os << now->tm_mon + 1 << " ";
        os << now->tm_year + 1900;

        return os;
    }

    // Could be converted to a static method,
    //  since DateTime has no internal state
    std::string str() const
    {
        // the following 3 lines can be replaced by
        //  return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*this);
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << *this;
        return ss.str();
    }

    operator std::string() const
    { return str(); }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In a world without RVO/NRVO this should avoid the copy construction in a pre C++11 standard library. In a post C++11 library with move constructor for string it still avoids the move constructor being called; it's probably a trivially small difference but still the OP was asking how to do better.

(And yes I agree the inheriting from string is ugly but it does work.)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DateString : public string {

public:
DateString() : string()     {

    stringstream ss;
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

    ss << now->tm_hour << ":";
    ss << now->tm_min << ":";
    ss << now->tm_sec << " ";
    ss << now->tm_mday + 1 << " ";
    ss << now->tm_mon + 1 << " ";
    ss << now->tm_year + 1900;

    append(ss.str());

}
};

int main()
{
    cout << DateString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Inheriting from `std::string` is just (morally) wrong. 2) The code the OP already has will also avoid copy construction even without NRVO.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I know this is not thread safe and all that and I'll probably be downvoted to hell end back, but I've seen the following in a library that I'm using (CERN's ROOT):

```
const char * myfunc(){

  static std::string mystr;

  /*populate mystr */

  return mystr.c_str();
}
```

This only works if you know that no one will ever be so stupid as to hold on to the pointer.

This is a way of having a temporary that will not leak no matter what.

Comment: That was fast DeadMG! :-)  The problem with this answer is that it invokes undefined behavior.  By the time client sends the pointer to `cout`, the local `mystr` has already deleted the character array to which that pointer points to.  It might work, and I have no doubt Simon tested before posting.  But it also might not work.  In a multithreaded environment the same application might sometimes work and sometimes not.

Comment: @Howard : `mystr` is static, so there's no destruction of it here; I think DeadMG's nit is that this isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @ildjarn:  So it is! Thanks for the correction.  I completely overlooked that.  What's the convention here?  Delete my comment because it might confuse people, or leave it up so they can read this one too?

Comment: @Howard : Your call; it might confuse people, or it might be clarifying for other readers that make the same mistake you did when reading the code. :-]